# Change password form which validates old password with spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

Im using grails for web development and spring security for authentication and authorization.

I want to make a simple form to allow users to change their password. This is a form with three password fields. The first is supposed for the current (old) password. The second and third are for the new password with validation to prevent accidental wrong typing.

The problem is that I cant figure out the proper way to validate the old password against the current one. I thought about doing it manually by using the `springSecurityService.encodePassword` function and comparing the hashes. But I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

This form is only accessible for users which are already logged in. Asking for the password should stop an attacker from changing the password if they somehow got hold of the session (user forgot to log out for example)

Is there a spring security way to do this?

Comment: using `springSecurityService.encodePassword` looks good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [an example](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/12%20Password%20and%20Account%20Protection.html) in the Spring Security Core docs that uses `passwordEnconder`, but `springSecurityService.encodePassword` is fine too.

Comment: I have tested both approaches and they work perfectly. I stick to the password encoder since i think that this is more clean.

Comment: Looks like the documentation link listed is no longer valid, but I think this is the equivalent page: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/passwords.html#locking

Comment: @Michael that link you provided is dead too

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'm using in Grails 2.3 and spring-security-core-2.0-RC4.

```
import com.example.User
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService


class UserController {

   SpringSecurityService springSecurityService 

   def checkUserPasswordMatches(){
      //Get current user
      User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()    

      String currentPassword = params.password

      if (!springSecurityService.passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.getPassword(), currentPassword, null)) {
         log.info("INFO - Password does not match!"

         //TODO: Do something now passwords match...
      } else {
         log.info("INFO - Password matches existing user password!"

         //TODO: Do something after passwords mismatch...
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how it served me and I validate the confirmation of the new password.

```
def cambio= {
    def respuesta = [error: 1]
    SecUser user = springSecurityService.currentUser


    if (params?.j_password && params?.password && params?.old_password) {
        String oldPasword=params?.old_password
        String newPassword = params.j_password
        String newPassword2 = params.password

        if    (!springSecurityService.passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.getPassword(), oldPasword, null)) {

            respuesta.error=3
            render respuesta as JSON
        }else if(newPassword == newPassword2) {

        user.setPassword(params.j_password)
        user.save()
        respuesta.error=0
        render respuesta as JSON
      }else
      {
          respuesta.error=2
          render respuesta as JSON
      }

    }else{
    render respuesta as JSON
    }
}`
```